# Trying to avoid multiple single field unique indexes

Tags: sql-server

My company requries that each table have a uniqueidentifier.  However, most of the lookup tables have a numerical code for each entry.  For example, there is a list of privileges: 10-None, 20-View, 30-Edit and so on.  The code is essential and must be unique.  Alos, the text of the code "None", "Edit", etc also needs to be unique, so now I have two separate fields that each need to be unique.  Now I have to add a guid column.  That's now three separate fields in the table that each need to be unique.  This example uses a very simple list.  The code value is essential and also some of these tables equate to an enum.  I need both the code and the text.  Having three separate fields each with a unique index seems contrary to normal table design.

Is there a more common practice to avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: This question may belong to Database Administrators: http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What is the purpose of the `guid` column?

Comment: A surrogate key for a surrogate key where a natural key exists? Holy relational-redundancy Batman!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you would want to change that setup even though you have several unique  values already. We had a similar practice at my last employer where even though we had uniquely identifying fields everything had a unique identifier field.
     This was a good thing as there would be infrequent errors in the program that would cause duplicates to be entered erroneously, except for the identifier fields. This usually kept our program from crashing or returning incorrect data as we always joined on the identifier rather than the 'unique' fields that were not supposed to have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are placed on fields that are typically used when sorting or linking tables.  For example, let's say you have a "normalized" environment of Product Orders.  You would have one table for Customers, with a Customer ID and other info, and you would have one table with Orders, which woul dcontain the Customer ID.  You would index Customer ID in both tables, because you're going to frequently join those tables.

As far as a unique identifier, you don't need to index them for them to be unique.